# How can I generate a single .avro file for large flat file with 30MB+ data

Tags: avro, data-ingestion, avro-tools

currently two avro files are getting generated for 10 kb file, If I follow the same thing with my actual file (30MB+) I will n number of files.

so need a solution to generate only one or two .avro files even if the source file of large.

Also is there any way to avoid manual declaration of column names.

### current approach...

> spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1
>
> import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType}
>
> // Manual schema declaration of the 'co' and 'id' column names and types
>   val customSchema = StructType(Array(
>   StructField("ind", StringType, true),
>   StructField("co", StringType, true)))
>
> val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("comment", "\"").option("quote", "|").schema(customSchema).load("/tmp/file.txt")
>
> df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("/tmp/avroout")
>
> // Note: /tmp/file.txt is input file/dir, and /tmp/avroout is the output dir

Comment: Sorry I don't get it: So you have one input file and you want to generate 2 avro files out of it (instead of n you have right now). Is this correct? So your question is about how to do it with spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying number of partitions of your dataframe while writing the data as avro or any format. To fix this use `repartition` or `coalesce` df function.

`df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("/tmp/avroout")`

So that it writes only one file in `"/tmp/avroout"`

Hope this helps!